# Return nth child

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

Using the following statement I get a valis response for i = 1 but when trying i = 2 etc I get an array out of bounds exception, any pointers would be great!

```
AutoPilot resultNode = new AutoPilot();
resultNode.selectXPath("/top/level[@sev='4']/item/title/text()[i]");
resultNode.bind(vn);
int z = resultNode.evalXPath();
System.out.println("TEST: "+vn.toString(z));
```

Example XML:

```
<top>
  <level sev="4">
    <item>
      <title>gngsfjdsf</title>
      <p1>2</p1>
      <p2>2</p2>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>sdadad</title>
      <p1>2</p1>
      <p2>2</p2>
    </item>
  </level>
  <level sev="3">
    <item>
      <title>3214125421</title>
      <p1>2</p1>
      <p2>1</p2>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>kjhkjtnjy</title>
      <p1>1</p1>
      <p2>2</p2>
    </item>
  </level>
</top>
```

Comment: you need to test the condition in which the returned value from evalXPath is -1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
/top/level[@sev='4']/item/title/text()
```

indeed returns two values:

```
gngsfjdsf
sdadad
```

So you need to select only the second one, and you can do it by using parentheses:

```
(/top/level[@sev='4']/item/title/text())[2]
```

returns only

```
sdadad
```

The reason for your failure is that `.../text()[2]` tries to find the second text node of each of the found nodes, not the overall second node.

---

An even better solution is to select the second `item` node instead of trying to only get the second `text()` node of all the matched nodes...

```
/top/level[@sev='4']/item[2]/title/text()
```

Comment: sorry, just realised I referenced i = 1 and i = 2 then hardcoded the values in my example code. The expression I am using to try and get the second value is /top/level[@sev='4']/item/title/text()[2] but I get an out of bounds error when doing so, despite the fact the item should exist

Comment: @Ben Yep, I believe I am answering your real question. Both my expressions only match `sdadad`, just as you want. If not, please show us your expected output for both 1 and 2. I thought you want "gngsfjdsf" for 1 and "sdadad" for 2.

Comment: @Lino In XPath, arrays are 1-based.   [1] gets the first element, [2] gets the second.

Comment: @Lino No! https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates clearly says _"the first position is 1"_.

Comment: Of course! Thanks your second example where you return item[2] was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have a second text node for title element. so evalXPath() should return a -1 which is supposed to throw an out of bound exception.